# MATLAB access memory allocated by C++ application

Tags: c++, matlab, shared-memory

I have a C++ application that reads data packages from a hardware device. Each data package has a size of around 100 MB and I receive 5 packages per second. I would like to process the data in MATLAB directly after receiving it.

Currently, I am exporting the data package in a binary file and import it in MATLAB. However, as saving the file takes a long time, I would like to access it from MATLAB directly.

Is it possible in C++ to make the the memory accessible in MATLAB without storing it in a file on the hard drive? Are there other ways to create a (one-way) communication interface between C++ and MATLAB or is it possible to create a C++ function that returns the entire data package and can be called in MATLAB?

Comment: Read about mex Files. You can create a Matlab array managed by Matlab in C++ and then access the memory.

Comment: Read the MATLAB docs on interfacing with C++. You can call MATLAB from your C++ application, or you can call C++ library from within MATLAB (both with shared memory). You can also use inter-process communication and shared memory, but how that works differs between Windows and the other (POSIX) OSes.

Comment: As the C++ application has many dependencies, I would prefer not to compile the entire C++ class as a mex file. Is it possible to have a standalone C++ application that also controls the connection to the hardware device with a single function that can be called within MATLAB?

Comment: loop back socks?